# Room migrates from random number

Tags: android, database, android-room, database-migration, android-room-migration

Pleasant day to all,

Today I receive a weird crash from my android application. Here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

It seem to be a migration from a random number to my current db version. It also happen in 2 different devices, Samsung Android 13 and Transsion Android 11 respectively. I hope someone can help me with this.